# read local text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, visualization

I have a local `test.txt` file that I need to read into variable in JavaScript and send that variable to `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()` to create a chart. Text in `test.txt` file is in right format (I tried to copy it directly into function and it works). But I don't know how to read that file into variable.

Comment: Googling `read local text file in javascript` gives me tons and tons of answers?

Answer (score 0):

Reading local fine js is not permitted how ever you can use jQuery script function to load the data